# What is the best practice to implement event triggering in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I have the following component:

```
function Counter({onCountChange}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // ...suppose we have somewhere else also using the count variable

  useEffect(() => {onCountChange(count)}, [count, onCountChange]);

  return (
    <div className="Counter">
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count+</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Count-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

So it would cause the circular triggering issue if we directly pass a function in, I see [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544260/5588279) to solve this issue is to use `useCallback` in the parent:

```
const handleCountChange = useCallback(() => {...}, [dependency])
```

This solution introduces more complexity to the parent component.

---

Another solution is to let the event triggering not depend on the `onCountChange`:

```
useEffect(() => {onCountChange(count)}, [count]);
```

But this solution will not handle the change of the prop `onCountChange`, if the parent component changes the prop, it will still use the old value **(I think)**.

---

We can also manually trigger the event without the `useEffect`:

```
<button onClick={() => {setCount(count + 1); onCountChange(count + 1)}}>Count+</button>
<button onClick={() => {setCount(count - 1); onCountChange(count - 1)}}>Count-</button>
```

---

Sorry for giving so many backgrounds, I just want to make the question clear enough.

So my question is, what is the best practice to trigger an event in a reusable component? Especially if we have multiple places to trigger in the component? Is the manually triggering the best practice? **Or is there something that allows us to use the `useEffect` but neither introduces more complexity nor loses the ability to track the changes of the event function?**

Disclaimer: I am not good at React at all, so I might miss something obvious.

Comment: you should pass all dependiencie to useEffect array. if you pass the same onChangeCount (eg. useCallback) then it don't retriger useEffect. that aproach is ok.

Comment: Yeah, is there something that I can memorize the `onChangeCount` inside the child component instead of the parent component? I think... it is impossible, right?

Comment: are solution but.... if you don't change reference of onChangeCount. then this don't trigger render child component and don't trigger useEffect.